# While Loop does not function when needed

Tags: python-3.x

The fighting code I have here will simply sit when executed once, and does not crash nor do anything. What I want it to do is loop back and allow the battle to continue until the beast dies (I will add player later)

I am new to Python and still do not understand a lot about it, meaning I cannot see what is wrong with my code.

Initially, I swapped `if damage==0` to elif, but the code will still sit and do nothing indefinitely. It does not break either.

Any help would be appreciated.

````
a=1
z=int(30*a**2)
y=random.randint(0,0)
x=0
if y == 0:
    print("A wild Ragnabeast appeared!")
    z=int(30*a**2)
    b=int(30)
    c=random.randint(0,5)
    fight= True
    while fight == True: # Here is where the loop is supposed to start. The issue is that it starts once, and never again.
        user_input=input("What will player do? You can run or attack.")
        if user_input=="run":
            break
        elif user_input=="attack":
            print("The player punched the Ragnabeast!")
            d=int(random.randint(0,5))
            b = b - d
            if d==0:
                    print("The player missed.")
                    x+=1
            elif d!=0:
                    print("The player dealt",d,"d.")
                    print("The Ragnabeast has",b,"HP left.")
                    x+=1
            if a=="1":
                    d=random.randint(0,5)
                    d=int(random.randint(0,5))
            if d==0:
                    print("The Ragnabeast rammed into the player!")
                    print("The player took",d,"damage.")
                    z-=d
            if d==1:
                    print("The Ragnabeast bit the player!")
                    print("The player took",d,"damage.")
                    z-=d
            if d==2:
                    print("The Ragnabeast hit the player with its tail!")
                    print("The player took",d,"damage.")
                    z-=d
            if d==3:
                    print("The Ragnabeast spewed flames into the player!")
                    print("The player took",d,"damage.")
                    z-=d
            if d==4:
                    print("The Ragnabeast launched a rock at the player!")
                    print("The player took",d,"damage.")
                    z-=d
            if d==5:
                    print("The Ragnabeast's piercing stare shocked the player!")
                    print("The player took",d,"damage.")
                    z-=d
            if z <= 25:
                    print("The Ragnabeast leaks propane. It roars in pain.")
            if z <=10:
                    print("The Ragnabeast's flames start to die out. It will die soon.")
            while z != 0:
                    fight = True
            else:
                    print("The Ragnabeast has died.")
                    fight = False

                                ```
````

Answer (score 0):

If the `True` value isn't working, you should just be able to use strings in place of it.

ex:

`fight = True` turns into `fight = "true"`

`fight = False` turns into `fight = "false"`

`while fight == True:` turns into `while fight == "true":`

It's a pretty ghetto workaround, but it should work.

Also, I noticed that the names of some of your variables are just letters. Not trying to nag, but that's considered a bad habit in the coding community. Try to give them more descriptive names.

I hope I helped!

Comment: Did you notice that his name is literally TerribleatNamingAnything? :)

Comment: @TheMaker lol I noticed the name, but I somehow missed the connection haha